# magento test website creation

Tags: magento-1.6

I followed steps in below link and created test website. 
http://www.host1plus.com/tutorials/cms-tutorials/magento/magento-website-setup/how-to-create-magento-test-production-sites

But product links on test website are still pointing to original website. I have done changes to local.xml and core_config_data. i also removed the contents of cache directory

please let me know what might be the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the product links that are pointing towards the old website you will probably require a reindex.

Either via the Magento admin System > Index Management or via ssh

```
cd shell
php indexer.php --reindexall
```